# Log out of a LinkedIn session in Android

Tags: android, session, linkedin-api, logout

I have successfully integrated LinkedIn login functionality in my Android application. But I have failed to implement logout functionality.

Can anyone help me find a suitable solution? I have tried to clear all application data - but still no success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess logout is not possible using any FB,Twitter,LinkedIN rest API.

Comment: Thanks for reply,I did logout in FB,Twitter but for linkedIN i am confused.

Comment: @KushalShah please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675384/how-to-create-an-api-for-shipping-extension-to-work-in-android-app

Answer (score 7):

The LinkedIn application is using "single sign on", so once you log in to the app you can't log out from LinkedIn in your own app, unless you explicitly log out within the LinkedIn app. However, we can clear the session to make `accesstoken` `null` using following line of code, which will clear the session:

```
LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).clearSession();
```