# Shipping charges are not saving in Database if we added Product to cart through Android App

Tags: android, magento, soap

we are using 2 shipping methods in our site.

1. Table rate shipping method
2. Custom shipping method  [ extension]

we are doing **Android** app for our magento site.

when we use default shipping methods [ example :  "**Table rate shipping method** " ,code : "tablerate_bestway" ] shipping charges are working fine in site and in andriod app.

when we use custom shipping method [ example : "**custom shipping method 1**" , code "ship_ship" ] shipping charges are working fine in site **but we are getting "0" as shipping charges in android app** Because in APP, its not saving in "sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate " table

this is the problem. what we need to do so that shipping charges should work in andriod app when we use custom shipping method.

Comment: yes, create custom api for that so by this way you can access this method very easily.

Comment: ya, but client dont want that, we have to check why we are not getting shipping chrages in app?

Comment: problem is in app, if we add to cart its not saving in database.